# I need a Coldfusion Email Open Tracking solution

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I need to track email opens. This is for important emails such as flight bookings for clients.

The email is sent using cfmail.
I tried something I found that is basically just a image tag referencing a cfm page with url parameter that is included in the HTML email

```
<cfmail to="someaddress.com" from="someaddress.com" subject="SUBJECT" type="HTML">
 <img src="http://somedomain.com/test.cfm?id=1" />
</cfmail>
```

This does not work. I only tested on Gmail.

I have seen some examples in PHP but don't know PHP. Anyone tried this with CF?

Comment: Please elaborate on "This does not work".

Comment: The test.cfm page is not being executed when the email is opened.

Comment: There are a number of reasons that might not work...
1 - It's an email with just an "image" gmail might decide not to show that image
2 - What is the response to the test.cfm, I'm make sure that you are responding with an image cfcontent (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfcontent.html) is your friend here.
3 - The html of the email isn't "valid" try something that starts with <html> and ends with </html>
It's worth getting this working within an email client that you have a lot more control of and then trying it in gmail / hotmail etc.

Comment: Thanks Benny. I will have a look at this.

Comment: Worked with cfcontent. Thx Benny.

Comment: I'd highly recommend saving the stat/hit and then performing a 302 Redirect instead of using CFContent or you could end up DDOSing yourself whenever you send emails.  A better option would be to use a transactional email service provider like SparkPost.

Comment: Is the image/page on a publicly available site?  GMail proxies images, so it's not you opening the image but GMails servers

Comment: I tested it properly and the Gmail servers do not open the image. The tracker page only registers the hit once the email has been opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your test.cfm looks like this

```
<cfparam name="URL.id" default="">
    <cftry>
        <cfquery>
            UPDATE
        </cfquery>
        <cfcatch>
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>

<cfcontent type="image/jpg" file="#application.ABSOLUTE_PATH#resources\img\pixel_white.jpg">
```

Comment: I recommend using CFLocation and adding a random parameter to the image URL. This way the CF thread completes the request faster and isn't responsible for serving up the image.  (<cflocation url="/resources/img/pixel_white.jpg?a=#GetTickCount()#">  (Unless you want to attempt to add assign a cookie at the same time.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a service like [SparkPost](https://www.sparkpost.com/features/email-api-integration/)?  They offer 100,000/msg per month for free and can automatically track deliveries, opens & click-thrus on all links.  To send messages, you can use either SMTP *(1 per recipient)* or API *(1 message w/array of receipients)*. (I highly recommend using [CFX_HTTP5](http://adiabata.com/cfx_http5.cfm) w/API because their IPs are cloud-based and may change. [CFHTTP caches DNS "forever"](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-3944218).)

SparkPost also offers [webhooks](https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/1976204) so that you can have all event data (bounce, open, spam complaint, etc) posted back to your ColdFusion server via a background API. We've found this approach to be vastly superior to attempting to track it ourselves by serving up images w/tracking codes.  We also use webhooks to automatically unsubscribe any bounced email addresses.